# Type object 'By' has no attribute 'Link_text'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

Get tired to guess proper syntax. Please, help me out with my problem! Writing code in Python3.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/users/vp/desktop/Python/chromedriver")

try:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    login = driver.find_element(By.Link_text, 'Forgot password?').click()

finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

"Forgot password?" html:

a class="_2Lks6" href="/accounts/password/reset/" tabindex="0" xpath="1">Forgot password? a>

Answer (score 2):

I would change "Link_Text" to "LINK_TEXT" reason being selenium requires it to be in "all caps" or else it won't recognize the By. Method

I assume the original poster has already figured this one out or reverted to the depreciated method. I just wanted to add this answer for anyone else whom may have the same error without realizing the issue instead of being forced to use a depreciated method.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not a syntax error, but trying to access an attribute that is not there for an object.
you can read about this here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError

In your case, `By` (object) does not have an attribute called `Link_text`.

I guess supported attributes for `By` are listed here:
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/common/by.html#By

or

you can do the following to list the attributes

```
dir(By)
```

Comment: Please define a syntax error for me.